# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After update my OS to Maverics im unable to make new project in rails. I always see only:

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant LinksController
```

or

```
   Unable to autoload constant LinksController, expected 
   /Users/xxx/DEPLOY/yyyy/app/controllers/links_controller.rb to define it
```

when i try to make:

```
<%= link_to 'abc', link_path(f) %>
```

My LinksController is an empty controller with only:

```
def show
end
```

What is wrong? Im unable to make any new project.

Comment: Are there any spaces in `/Users/xxx/DEPLOY/yyyy/app/controllers/links_controller.rb`?

Comment: there were some problems with two rails 4.0.0 and 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925323/why-i-get-no-route-matches-get-session-while-its-using-delete-in-routes-fi).

Here is What happened, I was using Rails 4.0.2, which seems it cause issues with jQuery and/Or Turbolinks.

When I downgraded Rails version to "4.0.0" in Gemfile and 'bundle update', I got no more issue.

Checkout your Rails version, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a module name TwitterRETRIEVER, while Rails seems to looking for TwitterRetriever. After correct this to follow Rails naming standard, this problem is gone.