# Why i get No route matches [GET] "/session" while it's using DELETE in routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-mavericks

I'm working on Rails4 app, and using Monban for authentication.
When I run `rails g monban:scaffold` it creates several files such as:

routes.rb

```
resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = authenticate_session(session_params)
    sign_in(user) or set_flash_message
    respond_with user, location: root_path
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def session_params
    params.require(:session).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

when I run `rake routes` i get:

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern            Controller#Action
       root GET    /                      homes#show
    session POST   /session(.:format)     sessions#create
new_session GET    /session/new(.:format) sessions#new
            DELETE /session(.:format)     sessions#destroy
      users POST   /users(.:format)       users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)   users#new
```

Inside `views/layouts/application.html.erb` I added:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
    <%= current_user.username %>
    <%= link_to 'Sign out', session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Sign in', new_session_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_path %>
<% end %>
```

When I run the app, I can Sign in but when I 'Sign out' I get an error:
    `No route matches [GET] "/session"`

From what I see here "as I understand", destroy is looking for GET while it's using DELETE as it shouting above, Right??

What am I missing here or what is wrong?
Thanks

**== UPDTAE ==**

It seems like, it's related to JavaScript error, because I disabled jQuery from application.js. The reason for that is, I got an error `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant HomesController` when I ran the app for it's 1st time after created it. Here are what I had changed, added 'Monban' gem, added `root to: 'homes#show', via: :get` to routes and created HomesController with a show method.

When I searched online, I found others fixed similar issues 'if not the same' by disable jQuery from application.js.

When I did that, the app worked fine, but later on I ran into that issue above.

Now to get fix both issue I got rid of 'Turbolinks' gem and it's association across the app.

Searching more about `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant HomesController` issue, I found [Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767202/circular-dependency-detected-while-autoloading-constant) which is an interesting to know "if this is true" that Maverics could be the reason. Last week I updated my OSX from Mountain Lion to Maverics, before that I had never faced any similar issues.

I don't know what is causing these issues, does any know? I hope not Maverics.

Comment: It could be a javascript error in the page which prevents the link to use the `DELETE` verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like The issues I'm facing are related to Rails new version 4.0.1 and 4.0.2. Apparently "*which is not sure*" that Rails new version has problem with Turbolinks and/or jquery. May be this is a bug.

When I downgraded Rails version from `4.0.2` to `4.0.0`, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Like said egyamado : you need to include jquery_ujs in your layout.